# Who is the mysterious user @67275?

Tags: discussion, users

I was poking around in WB, and I found [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/67275/67275?tab=topactivity) user, who had bountied [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221085/a-mathematical-problem-that-no-computer-can-solve-but-a-human-can) question. However, this user has 1 rep, bountied the question with 100 reputation, and, and here's the most confusing part: They've neither answered nor asked any questions.  I don't think they've used an association bonus, b/c none of their listed sites have them showing with more than 200 rep.

Their username *is* their user number. Their most popular network question is a 20 upvote question of Gaming.SE, and on that site, their username is different: but again their user number.

Who is @67275?

Comment: I think you only need 100 points to get associated bonus

Comment: or probably if it's 200, they might  have bountied some of their rep on another site

Comment: @RPGlife You need 200 rep to get the association bonus, that I'm sure of. I don't know if you maintain the association bonus if you bounty your rep.

Comment: @67275 who are you?

Comment: his account is like 2 years old, he probably got the association bonus a very long time ago and spent it only recently

Comment: They have [offered 1300 rep](https://superuser.com/users/174140/174140?tab=bounties&sort=offered) in bounties on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess.. bounties are taken from the total SE points, rather than points for every individual sites ?

In that case 67275 can give away so many points, because the 67275 user has **140 accounts on SE**. According to his profile, starting with 101 points everywhere, together he may spend 14000 points this way.

See https://stackexchange.com/users/1927945/67275?tab=accounts

Comment: I don't think it's the case : [If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). Means that if we take first from WB:SE first, we fall under the threshold, as shown on their page. However, one with 101 reputation everywhere can put one 100 bounty on every websites if they so desire.

Comment: I looked again.. 67275 is only an existing account on WB. This user had relevant activity on SuperUser as 174140, https://superuser.com/users/174140/174140 , the other accounts have all different names (!!), but the 500 bounty on SU could very well have been handed out legally, he had high reputation there (218k reached) . Other bounties are 100's. He is giving away all points on all SE websites, in the last month he earned 50 altruist badges everywhere on SE :d

Answer (score 2):

They're a user, nothing particularly remarkable.

They have the association bonus from another site so they have 100 free rep points on every site they join. This gives them sufficient rep to issue a bounty. Usernames aren't unique across all of SO the fact that they have a different username on Gaming is pretty mundane.

Comment: I didn't know you could switch usernames between sites. Not that I am active on the other SEs x)...

Comment: I didn't know you can offer far more points as a bounty than you actually have in your account, how does this bounty system work ? Is it unlimited ? ref  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/219219/how-to-design-the-muscular-structure-of-a-dragon and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/209583/what-would-be-the-best-design-for-a-resistant-and-fast-humanoid-leg

Comment: @Goodies You spend your reputation to post a bounty. Points are spent when the bounty is issued, not when the reputation is distributed. Keep in mind that suspended users will have their reputation temporarily listed as 1 for the duration of their suspension.