# Why did I get rep for other stackexchange channels?

Tags: support

That's pretty much it. I may be missing a very basic tutorial-type section where this is probably explained. But I have checked! And found nothing. If there is actually something already written, please point me towards it so I can better understand.

That said, I am opening this question because I mostly participate in the Worldbuilding stack, but for my latest question I've received points in the Biology, Fantasy and Meta stacks for some reason. Thanks in advance for helping a newbie understand! :)

Comment: Was it the Association Bonus? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You have enough reputation to have a little bit of trust on every site

That's called the "[association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work)". When you reach 200 reputations, you gain this privilege. This in turns allows you to get straight-away some of the most basic privileges that aren't given to new users : commenting, etc...

### How can I check what happened recently to my reputation?

You can check your reputation changes per-site on your profile page, in the activity section. For instance :) :

[image: Reputation page]

Alternatively, you can check out your recent reputation gains and losses (and badges, too) at the top of the page. See the "recent" association bonus for another site :

[image: Recent reputation changes]

Comment: psss... you might want to edit the image in case there is something you don't want to be known

Comment: @L.Dutch Considering that anyone can look at others' reputation and badges, and that some people are looking for [seemingly random users](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/who-is-the-mysterious-user-67275)... Well, it's safer to assume everything is public and will be seen or induced at some point ^^. Even downvotes, to which I don't hide very much anyway (#hopefully-constructive-comments). I was more worried about avatars that might change, actually.

Comment: Votes are totally and completely anonymous. But if you are aware that you gave away that information and you are OK with it, fine with me

Comment: Thanks, took me a bit to really understand where and how to check out Rep form other stacks.

Comment: I would downvote you just because you use light mode on your wbesite, but it's not my style.

Comment: @L.Dutch the anonymity is voluntary, and I prefer not to maintain anonymity.  I often explain downvotes (-1 bla bla comment) and I feel close votes should not be anonymous, they *should always* be explained,. Ctv's hurt !